# Trying to log into Amazon.com to pull data, but getting an Enable Cookies response (using Go)

Tags: cookies, go, session-cookies

I'm trying to use Go to log into my account on Amazon to automatically pull some information, but I'm having trouble logging in because it complains about cookies. Here's a sanitized version of the code I was using:

```
package main

import (
"bytes"
"io/ioutil"
"net/http"
"net/http/cookiejar"
"net/url"
"strconv"
)

func CheckThis(AmazonUsername string, AmazonPassword string) error {

var LogonURL string

// Set the url
LogonURL = "https://www.amazon.com/ap/signin"

// Craft some form data
form := url.Values{}
form.Add("appAction", "SIGNIN")
form.Add("email", AmazonUsername)
form.Add("password", AmazonPassword)
form.Add("create", "0")
form.Add("appActionToken", “$VALUE”)
form.Add("openid.pape.max_auth_age", "$VALUE==")
form.Add("openid.identity", "$VALUE=")
form.Add("openid.assoc_handle", "$VALUE")
form.Add("openid.mode", "$VALUE")
form.Add("openid.ns.pape", "$VALUE==")
form.Add("openid.claimed_id", "$VALUE=")
form.Add("pageId", "$VALUE")
form.Add("openid.ns", "$VALUE=")

// Amazon sells cookies
cookieJar, _ := cookiejar.New(nil)

// Create a new client with the cookiejar in the struct...
client := &http.Client{
    Jar: cookieJar,
}

// Craft the request to send to the website with the form containing login info
req, _ := http.NewRequest("POST", LogonURL, bytes.NewBufferString(form.Encode()))

// Some more headers
req.Header.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
req.Header.Add("Content-Length", strconv.Itoa(len(form.Encode())))
req.Header.Add("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.8")
req.Header.Add("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8")
req.Header.Add("Connection", "keep-alive")
req.Header.Add("Host", "www.amazon.com")
req.Header.Add("Referer", "https://www.amazon.com/ap/signin")
req.Header.Add("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests", "1")
req.Header.Add("Origin", "https://www.amazon.com")
req.Header.Add("Cache-Control", "max-age=0")

// And we're off to the races...
resp, _ := client.Do(req)

// What was in the response?
charResponse, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
resp.Body.Close()

// Write response body to a text file with title of…
_ = WriteOutputToFile(string(charResponse), “response.html")

// All done!
return nil
}
```

The $VALUE entries are because I'm not sure if the strings are significant to my account so I removed them; these are values I pulled from the developer tools of a Chrome login session. I also removed err checks for brevity.

The reply page  (opening response.html on my drive within Chrome) looks like this:
[image: Amazon Response]

What am I missing in order to keep the cookie with the client req/resp for the sign-in and later pages?

Or am I missing something where the response page I save is trying to pull elements from Amazon when I render the HTML, and the cookie issue is because the browser would be missing cookie information when I'm trying to view the results from the Go application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure Amazon uses different data every time when you try to login so better to parse login form. Here is example

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
    "net/http/cookiejar"
    "net/url"
    "github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery"
    "log"
)

func checkError(err error) {
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}

func CheckThis(AmazonUsername string, AmazonPassword string) error {
    cookieJar, _ := cookiejar.New(nil)

    client := &http.Client{
        Jar: cookieJar,
    }

    res, err := client.Get("https://www.amazon.com/gp/sign-in.html/ref=ord_cart_unrec_signin")
    checkError(err)

    doc, err := goquery.NewDocumentFromResponse(res)

    form := url.Values{}
    doc.Find("form[name='signIn'] input").Each(func(i int, s *goquery.Selection) {
        name, exist := s.Attr("name")
        if exist {
            value, exist := s.Attr("value")
            if exist {
                form.Add(name, value)
            }
        }

    })
    form.Set("email", AmazonUsername)
    form.Set("password", AmazonPassword)

    req, _ := http.NewRequest("POST", "https://www.amazon.com/ap/signin", bytes.NewBufferString(form.Encode()))
    req.Header.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")

    res, err = client.Do(req)
    checkError(err)
    defer res.Body.Close()

    charResponse, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)

    ioutil.WriteFile("response.html", charResponse, 0777)

    return nil
}

func main() {
    CheckThis("", "")
}
```

Comment: This looks like it worked! I'm still testing some more items, but the returned response body is very very promising! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Amazon's index is setting this (and much more) cookies on my browser:

[image: amazon cookies]

I suppose you need to set them into cookiejar in order to simulate a browser (amazon excepts that from your request, so is telling you have no cookies enabled because there isn't a required security value).

I agree with @JimB, you should be using Amazon SDK. Is there any reason why you are not doing this way?

Best regards.

Comment: I'm trying to pull information about my account, information like purchase history. It looked like the SDK was for managing their cloud services; data buckets, VM's, etc...was I mistaken?

Comment: Yes and no ... you can get an access token directly from your account (if I remember well) then pass it as an argument to a simple tool that does the amazon OAuth stuff. You may not even need an SDK. What data you want to get from your profile?

Comment: Recent order history, mainly.